# JAVA Open browser with a specified website

Tags: java, uri

I have found that this code:

```
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(URI);
```

will open up the users default browser and go to the specified URI. The problem that i am having is i cant figure out what the URI is. I want to open up google maps, http://maps.google.com/maps/search/, but the URI does not accept a string.

Does anyone know what the URI would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[java.net.URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) is a type in Java SE7.

```
URI myUri = URI.create(urlString);
```

Comment: Thank you for replying so fast. This code works. Try catch is also needed for it to work in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
URI openIt=new URL("http://maps.google.com/maps/search/").toURI();
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(openIt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Construct the URI with a String directly will do:

```
URI uri = new URI("http://maps.google.com/maps/search/");
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri);
```

Another approach is to use the static method create()

```
URI uri = URI.create("http://maps.google.com/maps/search/");
```

Remember to handle exceptions.